# Is onclick attribute redundant after href attribute?

Tags: javascript, html

In the below code,

```
<div id="content">
    Here is my <a href="javascript:(function(){ 
        _my_script=document.createElement('SCRIPT');
        _my_script.type='text/javascript';
        _my_script.src='file:///D:/Access/bookmark/bmlet.js';
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(_my_script);})();">
    bookmarklet</a>
</div>
```

in addition to bookmark functionality, `javascript:` URI scheme allows you to invoke the JavaScript code that can inspect/update DOM of current page on **click** event of anchor tag(`a`),

Another example, where,

`<a href="JavaScript:void(0)" onClick="alert('Hello');">Say Hello</a>`?

can be written as,

`<a href="JavaScript:{alert('Hello');}void(0)">Say Hello</a>`?

So, What is the purpose of html attribute `onclick`?

Comment: It's just an alternative; either way you're using obtrusive JavaScript with a ridiculous maintenance overhead should you ever want to change anything. Moving your JavaScript outside of your HTML is - imho, etc - much better, and makes updating and maintaining much easier.

Comment: `onclick` is not alternative, because `javascript:` URI scheme also provides bookmark functionality

Comment: Also there is no `onClick` event, perhaps you mean `onclick`

Comment: Is bitcoin redundant after my local currency? Bitcoin is not alternative, because my local currency also provides highstreet retail funcationality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The onclick attribute appears redundant because you are using a link as a button. That is semantically incorrect and misleading: a link navigates to a different location, a button performs an action. If you want to perform an action, use a button element.

If you need a link, then the href attribute should be the link target and the onclick should be used to attach additional behaviour.

#### Edit

Additional information regarding the purpose of links and buttons.

The HTML 5.1 specification [regarding links](http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/semantics.html#the-a-element):

> If the a element has an href attribute, then it represents a hyperlink
>   (a hypertext anchor) labeled by its contents.

A [button](http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/semantics.html#the-button-element) has no other purpose than to be activated, which is inferred by:

> The type attribute controls the behaviour of the button when it is activated.

It is also considered poor practice to insert complex scripts into HTML attributes as it makes maintenance more difficult, contributing to [*technical debt*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_debt).

Comment: "*If you need a link, then the href attribute should be the link target and the onclick should be used to attach additional behaviour.*" - I understand, and appreciate, this; but you've provided no evidence to substantiate your assertion. While I understand that you're trying to help, you're answering a *very* poor question - that reads like a rant disguised as a 'discussion' - with an answer that is itself poor, and opinion-based.

Comment: 1) OK Rob. But, If `href` attribute should be the link target, then why javascript code is allowed as `href` value using `javascript:` URI scheme?##### 2)Please ignore the coding style of inserting complex scripts into HTML attributes, as it is secondary to this topic.

Comment: @overexchange the reason _JavaScript_ works in a _href_ (prefixed `javascript:`) isn't because _href_ was meant to work this way, it is because setting the URL is an easy way to inject something, especially in programs which use a _WebView_ that aren't necessarily a _browser_ or from legacy before browsers came with an easy-to-access _Console_, so the URL input was designed to work this way. It has stuck around because of the popularity of bookmarklets, but it does pose a real security risk as it is quite an easy XSS vector.

Comment: @PaulS. So, In `href`, `javascript:` URI scheme has stuck for bookmarklet reasons , which makes sense to me. Does that infer that I should use `href="#"` instead of `href=javascript:void(0)` to stay on same page? Because `href="javascript:void(0)"` is a wrong usage, semantically.

Comment: If it's not meant to navigate the page, consider if you want an `<a>` at all and not some other element.

Comment: @DavidThomas—the evidence is that it's semantically incorrect. If you like I'll include links to the HTML specification, but that should not be necessary.